# Is label tag valid for XHTML 1.0 Transitional?

Tags: xhtml, label, xhtml-transitional

My question in short is the `<label>` tag, is it work for `XHTML 1.0 Transitional` validation ?

**For example**

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <label>Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
    <label>Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="sbmtLogin" value="login" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<label>` (and [validating](http://validator.w3.org) would have told you this) is but `<lable>` (which you had before editing) is not.

It is, however, useless unless you associate it with a form control (via the `for` attribute or placing the form control as a descendant of the label element).

Comment: Sorry, I mean `<label>`.

Comment: In your opinion or the correct, Do I add it or not (leave the word without label tag). ex `<label> text </label>`  or `directly text`

Comment: Definitely use it, but use it correctly. Either put for the form control inside it, or add a suitable `for` attribute.

Comment: Right. When written like this, it doesn't have any function.

Comment: Do you mean use it as either `<label> Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></label>` or `<label for="username"> Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" />` ?